# Merge timeranges to one timerange php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, merge

I have some results for example:

```
10:00 - 10:00
11:00 - 11:00
12:00 - 12:00
13:00 - 13:00
17:00 - 17:00
18:00 - 18:00 
19:00 - 19:00
20:00 - 20:00
```

I want to merge all these timeranges into one or multiple timeranges.
So in this case the output has to be:

```
10:00 - 13:00
17:00 - 20:00
```

I tried something with pushing all these results in an array, then check for each array value if the last array value is the same as the current array value - 60*60 (an hour), if yes --> merge time

But with this method I cannot get 2 or more timeranges.

Has anyone an idea?
Iam working with MySQLi and PHP.

Comment: Your example is bit weird because the time ranges you provide is NOT actually overlapped. So they should not be merged.

Comment: there must be always 1 hour gap? I.e between `10:00-13:00` there will be no data like `10:30 - 11:45`

Comment: Correct, only one hour difference

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT NEW:** I found myself an answer.

For the people who like to know how I did this.

1. Get all times
2. Check if last time is equal to current time - 1 hour (so it would be the next hour)
3. If yes --> Remove last array value
4. If not --> It would mean there is a gap of minimal 2 hours so close the timerange (push the last array value)
5. Now you have an array with all timeranges `Array ( [0] => 04:00 [1] => 04:00 [2] => 09:00 [3] => 14:00 [4] => 18:00 [5] => 20:00 )`
6. Slice the array by 2 with a for loop for count(array) times.
7. And then you have specific time ranges.

Iam very bad at explaining stuff, Iam sorry for that.
My code now:

```
$last_v = null;
$array_times = array();
```

-- $van_besch = a database fetched value --

```
if (strtotime($last_v) == (strtotime($van_besch) - 60*60)) {
         array_pop($array_times);

    }else{
        array_push($array_times, $van_besch);
    }

    $last_v = $van_besch;

array_push($array_times, $van_besch);
```

If every value is pushed into the array. Slice the array:

```
for ($i =0; $i < count($array_times); $i = $i + 2) {
    $new_array_1 = array_slice($array_times, $i, 2);
$van_new = $new_array_1[0];
$tot_new = $new_array_1[1];


if (strtotime($van) <= strtotime($tot) && strtotime($van_new) <= strtotime($tot_new) && strtotime($van) < strtotime($tot_new) && strtotime($tot) > strtotime($van_new)) {
        $error ='<div style="background-color:#ffccba; border:2px solid #d63301; border-radius:3px; color:#d63301;  padding:5px;">Tijd '.$van_new.' - '.$tot_new.' niet beschikbaar!</div>';
    }
}
```

Iam happy that I found the solution myself (:

---